# Deleting item from Listview in onActivityResult

Tags: android

I'm hoping that someone here could help me. I'm trying to delete an item from my Listview by clicking a button from another activity. I'm sending a an intent and resultcode in the onActivityResult to the activity that contains the listview but nothing is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Delete Button Activity

```
 private void deleteClicked() {
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra("myReminder", item);
        getActivity() .setResult(12, result);
        getActivity().finish();

    }
```

ListView Activity

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.e(TAG, "REMOVE CALLEDcode");
        if (requestCode == 05) {
            if (resultCode == 12) {

                Chops  item = (Chops) data.getSerializableExtra("myReminder");
                removeChop(item);
                refreshFragment();
            }

        }
    }


    private void removeChop(Chops item) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d(TAG, "REMOVE CALLED");
        for (Iterator iterator = SaveTheChops.listofchops.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Chops deleteChop = (Chops) iterator.next();
            if (match(item, deleteChop)) {
                iterator.remove();
                //SaveTheChops.addChop(getActivity());
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean match(Chops item, Chops deleteChop) {
        if (item.getmAlbum().equals(deleteChop.getmAlbum()) &
                item.getmArtist().equals(deleteChop.getmArtist()) &
                item.getmSong().equals(deleteChop.getmSong()) &
                item.getmAudio().equals(deleteChop.getmAudio()) &
                item.getmPic().equals(deleteChop.getmPic()) &
                item.getmSection().equals(deleteChop.getmSection()))

        { Log.e(TAG, "MATCH");
            return true;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, " NO MATCH");
        return false;

    }

    private void refreshFragment() {
        Log.e(TAG, "REFRESHED");
        Fragment frg = null;
        frg = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("ListFragmenttag");
        final FragmentTransaction ft =      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.detach(frg);
        ft.attach(frg);
        ft.commit();
    }

}
```

If it helps here is my ListAdapter

```
public static class ListViewDemoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Chops> implements  MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener {

        final String TAG = "MyChopActivty";
        private boolean isPlaying;
        private boolean isRecording;
        private List<Chops> mItems;
        MediaPlayer mPlayer;
        public Chops item;
        File audiofile = null;
        private int length;
        Intent intent, fileIntent;
        String mAudio;

        public ListViewDemoAdapter(Context context, List<Chops> items) {
            super(context, R.layout.each_item, items);

        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder viewHolder;


            if (convertView == null) {
                final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.each_item, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cover_photo);
                viewHolder.tvAlbum = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvAlbum);
                viewHolder.tvPlay = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listPly);
                viewHolder.tvSong = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvSong);

                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                final Button PIL = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listPly);
                final Button PAUSIL = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.listPause);
                PAUSIL.setEnabled(false);
                PAUSIL.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                PIL.setTag(position);

                PIL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();
                        Chops item = getItem(position);
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PLAY FROM LIST?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if (item.getmAudio() != null) {
                            mAudio = item.getmAudio();
                            Log.d(TAG, " from LISTPLAY   " + mAudio);

                            try {
                                playAudio(mAudio);
                                if (isPlaying) {
                                    PAUSIL.setEnabled(true);
                                    PAUSIL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    PIL.setEnabled(false);
                                    PIL.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                }
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                    }
                });

                PAUSIL.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "PAUSING", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        stopPlaying();
                        isPlaying = false;
                            PAUSIL.setEnabled(false);
                            PAUSIL.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            PIL.setEnabled(true);
                            PIL.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                });


            } else {

                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Chops item = getItem(position);
            viewHolder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(StringToBitMap(item.getmPic()));
            viewHolder.tvAlbum.setText(item.getmAlbum());
            viewHolder.tvSong.setText(item.getmSong());

            return convertView;
        }
```

Comment: If your onActivityResult is called from the fragment then you must define the onActivityResult() in the parent Activity as well, just define the onActivityResult() in the parent activity without any extra code, then it should work fine

Comment: I'm fairly new to android programming so could you please explain how and where to define?

Comment: I tried to add onActivityResult() to the parent activity but it still doesn't get called.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, Add a method to remove an item from your dataset inside your Adapter class. Something along the lines of:

```
public void remove(int position){
   mItems.remove(position);
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Then call `yourAdapter.remove(positionToRemove);` from the `onClick` of the Activity with the button.

Comment: I tried to add the method that you suggested but adding notifyDatasetChanged gives me an error. It say that the method notifyDatasetChanged needs to be created.  Also, when I tried to access the remove method from the onClick of the other activity it won't allow me to access it because it is static.

Comment: I was able to get my onActivityResult to be called but now the Listview isn't refreshing so the item stays in the list. Would you have anymore suggestion?

Comment: Update if anyone cares. My items are deleting now except when I only have one item in the list. Weird. not sure what is causing this behavior.

Comment: positon you have to pass, the first element position will be zero, if you are starting the position as 1, then you should start with 0, to delete the only one item pass the position parameter as 0(zero).